# Specify clustering key while creating a secondary index in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

Amazon's DynamoDB supports Global Secondary Indices where one can specify a different Partition key and Sort key to index the data.

Does Cassandra offers functionality to create secondary indices using a partition key and clustering key?

Answer (score 0):

Cassandra's feature which is analogous to DynamoDB's GSI (Global Secondary Index) feature is **Materialized Views**, and is almost identical to the DynamoDB feature and is probably what you are looking for. Don't be confused by Cassandra's "Secondary Index" feature, which is a different feature from DynamoDB's secondary indexes...

There is just one limitation in materialized views that I don't know if you care about (I didn't understand your exact use case): (https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql-oss/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlCreateMaterializedView.html)

> You can add a single non-primary key column from the base table.

In other words, if you have a base table with partition key p and clustering key c, and also two regular columns x and y, Cassandra does **not** allow you to create a materialized view (i.e., a GSI) whose partition key is x and clustering key is y (and p and c). The problem is that you're trying to add both x and y to the primary key of the view, and that is not currently supported. If you want to add just one (just x or just y), it will work.

ScyllaDB, which implements both CQL (the Cassandra API) and the DynamoDB API, supports this use case because it is needed for DynamoDB compatibility.